# Image translation confining boundaries

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am using `RenderTransform` to translate an image using manipulation delta events. The image if flicked away goes out of screen. How to restrict the image to stay inside a grid?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the delta events in such a way that your translations do not leave a container. This is from my earlier project (_scatterViewItemTransform is a CompositeTransform on my flicked item that is hosted inside of a Container (an ItemsControl with its ItemsPanel set to a Grid):

```
protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Manipulation delta does not take UI scaling into account
    var scaleString = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.QualifierValues["scale"];
    var scale = Double.Parse(scaleString) * 0.01;

    var x = _translateOrigin.X + e.Cumulative.Translation.X / scale;
    var y = _translateOrigin.Y + e.Cumulative.Translation.Y / scale;

    if (e.IsInertial)
    {
        while (x < Container.Padding.Left ||
            x > Container.ActualWidth - Container.Padding.Right)
        {
            if (x < Container.Padding.Left)
                x = -x + 2 * Container.Padding.Left;
            if (x > Container.ActualWidth - Container.Padding.Right)
                x = 2 * (Container.ActualWidth - Container.Padding.Right) - x;
        }

        while (y < Container.Padding.Top ||
            y > Container.ActualHeight - Container.Padding.Bottom)
        {
            if (y < Container.Padding.Top)
                y = -y + 2 * Container.Padding.Top;
            if (y > Container.ActualHeight - Container.Padding.Bottom)
                y = 2 * (Container.ActualHeight - Container.Padding.Bottom) - y;
        }
    }

    _scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateX = x;
    _scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateY = y;

    if (!e.IsInertial)
    {
        BringIntoBounds();
    }
}


public void BringIntoBounds()
{
    if (_scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateX < Container.Padding.Left)
    {
        _scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateX = Container.Padding.Left;
    }

    if (_scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateX > Container.ActualWidth - Container.Padding.Right)
    {
        _scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateX = Container.ActualWidth - Container.Padding.Right;
    }

    if (_scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateY < Container.Padding.Top)
    {
        _scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateY = Container.Padding.Top;
    }

    if (_scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateY > Container.ActualHeight - Container.Padding.Bottom)
    {
        _scatterViewItemTransform.TranslateY = Container.ActualHeight - Container.Padding.Bottom;
    }
}
```